# How do I select items in my dropdownlist from the controller?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

In my application I have a multi select list that fills up with a list of fruit

```
public ActionResult Index(int? userId)
{
    viewModel.FruitSelectList = viewModel.FruitList.Select(item => new SelectListItem { Value = item.iFruitID.ToString(), Text = item.sFruitName }).ToList();
    return View();
}
```

For reference here is what my model looks like:

```
public class Fruit
{
    public int FruitID {get; set;}
    public string FruitName {get; set;}
    public int UserID {get; set;}
}
```

I need to return all items in the database that matches a `userId`

```
var result = (from u in db.Fruit where u.UserID == userId select u).ToList();
```

But how do I show the `result` as items selected in my dropdownlist?

Comment: It is hard to understand what do you  want. Can you post the example pls

Comment: @Serge I am saying that I have a select list of fruit, and I want to show the list of fruit that are in the `result` list as selected within that select(dropdown)list

Comment: I can't  see any viewmodel and any fruitlist

Answer (score 2):

You don't show the `iFruitID` , `sFruitName` and `viewModel`in your code,so I changed some code to Achieve the desired effect.Here is my code:

Controller:

```
        //I don't know what's the `viewModel`,so I just create a `viewModel` class in controller
        public class viewModel
        {
            public List<SelectListItem> FruitSelectList { get; set; }
            public List<Fruit> FruitList { get; set; }
        }

        public  ActionResult Index(int? userId)
        {
            var data = new List<Fruit>()
            {
                new Fruit() { FruitID = 0, FruitName = "Apple", UserID = 1 },
                new Fruit() { FruitID = 1, FruitName = "pear", UserID = 1 },
                new Fruit() { FruitID = 2, FruitName = "watermelon", UserID = 2 },
                new Fruit() { FruitID = 3, FruitName = "cherry", UserID = 2 },
            };

            //For the convenience of testing, I hard-coded here,so I just select from `data`,If you want select from database,just use your original linq
            var result = data;

            if (userId != null) {
                result = result.Where(u => u.UserID == userId).ToList();
            }

            viewModel viewModel = new viewModel();

            viewModel.FruitList = result;
            //because you don't show the `iFruitID` and `sFruitName`,I just use FruitID and FruitName To replace them.
            viewModel.FruitSelectList = viewModel.FruitList.Select(item => new SelectListItem { Value = item.FruitID.ToString(), Text = item.FruitName }).ToList();
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

View:

```
@model DropdownList.Controllers.HomeController.viewModel

<select asp-items="@Model.FruitSelectList">
</select>
```

Page:

1.When there is no userId is passed into the method, DropDownList show all the options

[image]

2.when userId = 1, DropDownList only show the options which their UserId=1.

[image]